# angular-simple-format bower dependencies different from rails-assets dependencies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, bundler, bower

In my Gemfile I'm using rails-assets to load angular and a number of other bower packages:

```
gem 'rails-assets-angular', '~> 1.3.5'
#... others
gem 'rails-assets-angular-simple-format', '~> 0.9.2'
```

[angular-simple-format](https://github.com/RStankov/angular-simple-format/blob/master/bower.json) seems to be happy with any version of angular and any version of angular-sanitize:

```
"dependencies": {
  "angular": "*",
  "angular-sanitize": "*"
}
```

Why does `bundle update --source rails-assets-angular-simple-format` give me this error:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails-assets-angular":
  In Gemfile:
    rails-assets-angular-simple-format (~> 0.9.2) ruby depends on
      rails-assets-angular (= 1.2.21) ruby

    rails-assets-angular (1.3.5)
```

Is there another layer of dependency management that rails-assets imposes between the bower package and bundler? How do I see what it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that rails-assets does mess with dependencies. The `rails-assets-angular-simple-format` gem specifies the version of angularjs more strictly than the original bower project. From `rails-assets-angular-simple-format.gemspec`:

```
spec.add_dependency "rails-assets-angular", "1.2.21"
```

To solve I copied the original bower project into `vendor/assets/javascripts` and removed the rails-assets gem from the Gemfile.

Answer (score 0):

Although angular-simple-format accepts any version of angular or angular-sanitize, if you check the dependencies for angular-sanitize it requires angular 1.21 which is causing a conflict.

You would have to force rails-assets-angular to version 1.2.21 on the first line of your Gemfile.